# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars h[i]=(delta_tau*((sigma*x[i])**2))/(s*h[i-1]-delta_tau*r*h[i-1])

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as si
import sympy as sy
import math
H=1.0
K=100
T=1
s=0.95
r=0.04
sigma=0.025
delta_tau_temp=(s*(H**2))/((r*(H**2))+((sigma**2)*((106-H)**2)))
#N_tau-no of time steps, N_x- no of space points
N_tau = math.floor(T/delta_tau_temp) +1
#delta_tau -time step
delta_tau = T/(N_tau)
N_x =int((106/H) + N_tau)
h=np.zeros((N_x )) #increment for space points
x=np.zeros((N_x)) #space points
u=np.zeros((N_x,N_tau)) #2-D array
m_1 =100/H -1
m_2 =100/H +1
for i in range(N_x):
    if i <=(106/H-1):
        h[i]=H
        x[i]=H*i
    if i == 106/H :
        x[i]= H*i
        h[i]=(delta_tau*((sigma*x[i])**2))/(s*h[i-1]-delta_tau*r*h[i-1])
    else:
        x[i]=x[i-1]+h[i-1]
        h[i]=(delta_tau*((sigma*x[i])**2))/(s*h[i-1]-delta_tau*r*h[i-1])
for j in range(N_tau):
    if j==0:
        for i in range(N_x):
            u[i][0]=max(x[i]-K,0)
    else:
        if j<=(N_tau -m_1 -2):
            for i in range(N_x -j-1):
                 u[i][j]=((delta_tau*(((sigma*x[i])**2)-r*x[i]*h[i-1]))/(h[i-1]*(h[i-1]+h[i])))*u[i-1][j-1] +(1-(r*delta_t)-((delta_t*((sigma*x[i])**2))/(h[i-1]*h[i])))*u[i][j-1]+((delta_tau*(((sigma*x[i])**2)+r*x[i]*h[i]))/(h[i]*(h[i-1]+h[i])))*u[i+1][j-1]
                 print(u[i][j])
            else:
                if i in range(j-N_tau +m_1 +1, N_x -n-1 ):
                    u[i][j]=((delta_tau*(((sigma*x[i])**2)-r*x[i]*h[i-1]))/(h[i-1]*(h[i-1]+h[i])))*u[i-1][j-1] +(1-(r*delta_t)-((delta_t*((sigma*x[i])**2))/(h[i-1]*h[i])))*u[i][j-1]+((delta_tau*(((sigma*x[i])**2)+r*x[i]*h[i]))/(h[i]*(h[i-1]+h[i])))*u[i+1][j-1]
                    print(u[i][j])
```

I plan to obtain  the values of u[i][j] only for a certain number of grid points under some constraint on i as mentioned in the range of i. I do not understand where the mistake is. please could someone help

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be dividing by zero at `if i <=(106/H-1):` as H=1.0.
The error goes away by changing H to something > 1.

Comment: I had changed it to (106/H)-1 but still the error persists.

Comment: Another thing I observe, is twice meeting the equalto sign.
once in `if i <=((106/H)-1):` and then again in `i == 106/H`. Does defining `if i <((106/H)-1):` help?

Comment: but i<=((106/H)-1) and i==106/H are exclusive of each other. I mean i cannot satisfy both of the conditions together, then why shall there be twice meeting of the equal to sign?

Comment: I recommend getting familiar with the debugger here. The above error usually appears when there is a division by zero. Debugging will give you the line where this is happening.